# Loading a Json Object into javascript then using fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, canjs

I am new to javascript and I have loaded in a json object onto my site using canJS. The json is pretty long (>1000) lines and a fairly complex nested structure. Is there a way to load in the object so I can access the fields and subobjects?

I load in the object to an `<li>` element then I pass that element into another function. The problem is when it gets to that function I am unable to access the fields. When I look at the developer tools it has the textContext name defined correctly. Should I not be passing the `<li>`? What object do I pass to my function to manipulate the json object I retrieved using my service?

EDIT: How can I use json.Parse in canJs findAll()?

FYI: Using canjs library, c# 4.0 backend service, json is loaded from mongodb. I have seen that the correct object is returned in chrome developer tools

Comment: `JSON.parse(json_string)` gives you a regular javascript object from a string in JSON format ?

Comment: So you're receiving a json string and want to work with it as a javascript object? Why are you involving the DOM? Just parse the json (`JSON.parse(str)`) and work with it in javascript.

Comment: @JasonP see the edit? I understand that I should not pass the li but what exactly do I pass in? and how do I identify which object should be shown.

Comment: I'm not familiar with CanJS, but... _"I load in the object to an `<li>` element"_. Why? Why not assign the object to a variable or simply pass the object to your next function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use JSON.parse :[JSON.parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc836466%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

demo example :

```
var jsontext = '{"firstname":"Jesper","surname":"Aaberg","phone":["555-0100","555-0120"]}';
var contact = JSON.parse(jsontext);
document.write(contact.surname + ", " + contact.firstname);
```

Comment: Do you know i can use this with canJs.findAll()?

Comment: Here is the documentation how to implement your own .findAll: http://canjs.com/docs/can.Model.findAll.html#section_ImplementwithaFunction